# Auto Trigger notification on change in data in Mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I'm working on project, in which I'm writing data using powershell to Mysql. Then this data is fetch using NodeJS and projected in JSON format in a url. Now I have to show notification for success and failure on dashboard page. The question is how do I display either one of them according to the data in Mysql?(currently both conditions are visible)

How do I put check condition on JSON or directly on Mysql data? I'm open to use JQuery, Javascript or anything else. Any kind of help will really be appreciated.

Comment: Success or failure of what process?

Comment: would you please elaborate?, not sure what you want to achieve

Comment: Success or failure Of data being changed in Mysql. Which is written by powershell script

Comment: You should include the source code you currently have

Comment: I'll elaborate. There are notifications in dashboard for 2 conditions. Success which means everything is fine in environment and gives green. Second is red notification message which gathers data about servers giving errors in environment. I have all the data in Mysql for both conditions. But I only have to display either one of notifications (one at a time). How do I put checks  or check on  how to display data conditionally?

Comment: It's an enterprise code. I can't get it overhere. Infosec breach!,! :(